# Cannot redeclare class views_object

Tags: views

I moved a ready drupal 7 site from local to our webserver. It works - but just some time - then php gives the following error:

```
Fatal error: Cannot redeclare class views_object in /XXX/sites/all/modules/views/includes/base.inc on line 22
```

OK, I see the class views_object has already been declared. I wanted to fix that by

1. inserting a code snippet within the error-causing base.inc like this

   ```
   if(!class_exists(views_object) ) {return;} else {//CODE OF BASE.INC }
   ```

This doesn't work propperly.

1. Blacklisting the error-causing base.inc in the php.ini with

   ```
   opcache.blacklist_filename = /sites/all/modules/views/includes/base.inc
   ```

No result.

Does anyone have an idea how to solve that?

Thank you and best regards

Chris

Comment: Are you using APC?

Comment: No, the site isn't using apc.